# Turning a list of numbers separated by line breaks into a line

Tags: javascript

I have this code which is supposed to add pairs of numbers and print out new numbers.

```
var a = [580563, 750269, 127553, 478126, 490797, 919298, 440977, 549169, 935253, 48340, 605950, 859831, 26818, 336881, 438690];
var b = [498030, 704160, 346646, 544826, 898396, 192725, 382888, 590117, 172659, 534225, 592230, 235547, 502236, 327531, 405165];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var k = a[i] + b[i];
    console.log(k);
}
```

This returns this:

```
1078593
1454429
474199
1022952
1389193
1112023
823865
1139286
1107912
582565
1198180
1095378
529054
664412
843855
```

How do I turn it into this:

```
1078593 1454429 474199 1022952 1389193 1112023 823865 1139286 1107912 582565 1198180 1095378 529054 664412 843855
```

Thanks!

Comment: u want to edit the js itself, or its like another js file reads the above ouput from a file and need to do the necessary conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of logging the output for each index, concatenate a string and then handle output after the loop.

```
var a = [580563, 750269, 127553, 478126, 490797, 919298, 440977, 549169, 935253, 48340, 605950, 859831, 26818, 336881, 438690];
var b = [498030, 704160, 346646, 544826, 898396, 192725, 382888, 590117, 172659, 534225, 592230, 235547, 502236, 327531, 405165];

var k = '';
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    k += (a[i] + b[i]) + ' ';
}
console.log(k);
```

You can also keep track of each sum in an array, and join the elements with a space:

```
var k = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    k.push(a[i] + b[i]);
}
console.log(k.join(' '));
```

And as user [Arnauld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004841/arnauld) mentioned, this can be reduced into a one-liner by using the `map` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ES6 solution, using `.map()` and `.join()`:

```js
var a = [580563, 750269, 127553, 478126, 490797, 919298, 440977, 549169, 935253, 48340, 605950, 859831, 26818, 336881, 438690];
var b = [498030, 704160, 346646, 544826, 898396, 192725, 382888, 590117, 172659, 534225, 592230, 235547, 502236, 327531, 405165];

console.log(a.map((v, i) => v + b[i]).join(' '));
```

Or for browsers not supporting arrow functions:

```js
var a = [580563, 750269, 127553, 478126, 490797, 919298, 440977, 549169, 935253, 48340, 605950, 859831, 26818, 336881, 438690];
var b = [498030, 704160, 346646, 544826, 898396, 192725, 382888, 590117, 172659, 534225, 592230, 235547, 502236, 327531, 405165];

console.log(a.map(function(v, i) { return v + b[i] }).join(' '));
```

Comment: Oh that's such a prettier solution, thanks for adding!

Answer (score 1):

Using ECMAScript 6+, you can use the [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
var a = [580563, 750269, 127553, 478126, 490797, 919298, 440977, 549169, 935253, 48340, 605950, 859831, 26818, 336881, 438690];
var b = [498030, 704160, 346646, 544826, 898396, 192725, 382888, 590117, 172659, 534225, 592230, 235547, 502236, 327531, 405165];

console.log(...a.map((_, i) => a[i] + b[i]));
```

Note that this is not supported yet by all major browsers. See the [current compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator).